# How to get row count 3 table join and lambda expressions?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to get a row count for reports that a user has that match a particular channelId.  I've tried using lambda expressions without any luck.

```
int count = 
_reportsRepository.
    GetMany(r => r.UserId == user.Id && 
    (r.Charts.Any(cr => cr.Channels.Any(ch => ch.Id == channel.Id))).Any()).Count();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
int count = _reportsRepository.Where( 
                r => r.UserId == user.Id &&
                     r.User.Channels.Any(c => c.Id == channel.Id)).Count();
```

Comment: That looks too easy.  I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the answer.